# vb.net how can I make get the file name of text file?

Tags: vb.net

the name of textfile change daily, so how can I make the name of my textfile dynamic in the system?

```
   Dim fileNames = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\K3K3Pro\Ini\", 
   FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ini")
   Dim i = File.ReadAllLines("C:\K3K3Pro\Ini\" + fileNames + ".ini").Last
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to create a file using a random name, a name assigned based on the current date or you want to access the last file created by some other process, each time with a different name.

Comment: I want to access a file that is created by some other process each time with a different name.

Comment: I have a device that create every day a new textfile name, so i want that the system is flexible with this

Comment: You can get FileInfo list with [DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos?view=netframework-4.8), then order by the [FileSystemInfo.CreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime) property.

Comment: Im not familiar yet in C# @Jimi

Comment: These are .Net classes, it's the same with VB.Net. e.g., `dim fInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\TestFolder1").EnumerateFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime).First()`

Comment: Note that the MSDN Docs have a language selector in the upper band of the page.

Comment: @Jimi can you please post your answer?

Comment: I dont understand what you saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223594/discussion-between-mary-and-jimi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\K3K3Pro\Ini\", "*.ini")
        ' Process the list of .txt files found in the directory. '
        Dim fileName As String

        For Each fileName In fileEntries
            If (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)) Then
                'Read File and Print Result if its true
                'MsgBox(fileName)
            End If

        Next
```